# How to use @ViewChild for an html tag that been add dynamically in angular2 for dynamic loading?

Tags: angular

I have a component that using an external js file (datatables). When I'm rendering the table using datatable(), I'm creating the view of the table. I have the following:

```
<td class=" details-control"></td>
```

while locating the `<td>` I'm appending a component tag `<mycomponent #mycomponent></mycomponent>` using native element ref the question is if it still possible after adding the html element for component to somehow using the dynamic loading  (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html)

if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question completely. But I believe you are trying to render a table based on dynamic data.You could do something like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id></th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor= "let item of items">
            <td>item.id</td>
            <td>item.name</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No, this wasn't my question. I'm using datatable.js to render the table